# skip space in counting length using Validation Rule

Tags: validation

I am currently using rule as below, but it counts space as well. How can I update not to count space in validation rule?

```
IF(LEN(Name + ', ' + TEXT(demo_field)) > 95, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text)` - Substitutes new_text for old_text in a text string. Use SUBSTITUTE when you want to replace specific text in a text string

Ex : `IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Name + ', ' + TEXT(demo_field), ' ', '')) > 95, TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: trim is only for the leading space and ending space. I want to remove all the spaces INbetween and want the exact characters count only.

Comment: Apologies for not reading the question properly. I've updated my answer

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will check it out and will accept it after I test it :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `SUBSTITUTE` funciton:-

```
IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(text_field__c, " ", "")) > 95 , true,false)
```

Comment: And the point of this answer was? Did you improve on the accepted answer?